# Google Notifications fail sometimes with LinkageError, but work other times

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am using Azure Notification Hubs to send a notification to my Xamarin Forms app.

Sometimes (normally works the first time, then fails the second time) I am getting a Linker Error that the setVisibility method cannot be found.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='setVisibility' signature='(I)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;' in class Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
```

I am at a loss as to what could be causing this, especially given that it finds the setVisibility method about 50% of the time.

This seems to be reproducable on a KitKat phone (API Level 19)

Update:

What is interesting is that if I include the NotificationCompat.Builder from the NotificationCompat, **but do not use it** the problem seems to go away.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this happens is because this was introduced in API 21. In the Android documentation you can see in the top right corner of this method of when this was introduced:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setVisibility(int)

> Added in API level 21

Thus if you used this method on anything < API 21, it would crash because it does not exist. This is where you should be using `NotificationCompat.Builder` instead inside the `Support.v4` library:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html

Comment: Jon, thankyou for your comment.

I'm aware of the limitation - however it doesn't explain why it works 50% of the time?

Comment: I can't explain why as I'm not sure what the code is even calling. For all we know it could *sometimes* change the `visibility` and thus the API doesn't exist and throws the error. Is this from NuGet or the Component?

Comment: Jon it's from Nuget and the setVisibility is called every time.

Comment: Can you link the NuGet you are using? Just for clarification to look into.